# How to can I solve images compression in landscape view?

Tags: android, xml, landscape

I have designed an xml file contain nine images i.e.., 3 rows each row contain 3 images. in portrait view images are displayed very well but in landscape view first two rows images are displayed well and last row images are compressed as small images. my xml file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/back" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fire_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/fire_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fire_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fire_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/fire_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
            android:src="@drawable/fire_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fire_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView7"
            android:src="@drawable/fire_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView8"
            android:src="@drawable/fire_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

can you please tell me what I have done wrong...
 thanks in advance

Comment: try to use gridview.....

Comment: first try to see your images quality then try to use grid view in your program and  you can specify width and height easily in gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design similar layout in lanscape mode and put them in the "res/layout-land". make sure both the layouts has the same name.